# Mensagem "Terminated" com git add wp-content/

Tags: git

Estou recebendo uma mensagem ao adicionar a pasta `wp-content` no git.

Comando:

```
$ git add wp-content/
```

Resposta:
Terminated

O que poderia ser? Tentei `$ git add wp-content/ -f`, mas mesmo assim recebo a mensagem.

Comment: Se puder compartilhar a saída inteira do comando, bem como a versão do git, sistema operacional, etc. De qualquer maneira, tenta tirar essa / aí, só por desencargo.

Answer (score 2):

O **Git** é utilizado para versionamento de arquivos, e não de diretórios. Se você pretende ainda assim utilizar este diretório mesmo que vazio, utilize um arquivo *.gitignore*, e edite-o para não reconhecer arquivos dentro dela no versionamento.

Você encontra maiores informações sobre o .gitignore no [Help do GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).